# advise the decision to build a survey

Tags: php, ruby, survey

advise the decision to build a survey for users on RoR or PHP

Comment: Well that depends on which you know.. and if you know both, then you should already know which you prefer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why build when you already have an open source application existing in php? See http://www.limesurvey.org/

Answer (score 0):

For RoR. I'm finded this gem: http://github.com/breakpointer/surveyor